# Как избавиться от предупреждающих сообщений при сборке: warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, gradle

Как можно от этого избавиться, проект запускается, но ошибки появляются почему?

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:topBook:clean, :topBook:generateDebugSources, :topBook:mockableAndroidJar, :topBook:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :topBook:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :topBook:assembleDebug]
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 1 mins 11.107 secs
Information:88 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Вот Build Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jaloveast1k.topbook"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':serenity')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/loopingviewpager-master.jar')
}
```

Build Gradle Serenity

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.3-beta1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3-beta1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3-beta1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3-beta1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3-beta1.jar')
}
```

warrning

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:serenity:generateDebugSources, :serenity:mockableAndroidJar, :serenity:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :serenity:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :topBook:generateDebugSources, :topBook:mockableAndroidJar, :topBook:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :topBook:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for debugAndroidTest as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 5.223 secs
Information:0 errors
Information:5 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Попробуйте рассмотреть варианты в [похожем вопросе на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308010/what-is-the-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-warning-output-during-compilation). Также, думаю, стоит указать используемые версии JDK и `commons-logging`

Comment: Покажите свой *build.gradle*

Comment: @Barmaley, добавил

Comment: @defaultlocale, я вас не понял, куда нужно добавить `commons-logging`

Comment: Сообщения об ошибках ссылаются на классы `org.apache.commons.logging.`. Видимо commons-logging имеется среди зависимостей.

Comment: Пока криминала не вижу, покажите теперь build.gradle для проекта *serenity*

Comment: @Barmaley, добавил)

Comment: замените на строчку: `compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'`

Comment: @Barmaley , что заменить?

Comment: Вы что совсем что ли стерильные? Замените строчку `compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')`

Comment: @Barmaley теперь новые warrning - и появились)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53821/discussion-between-barmaley-and-java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью @Barmaley.

1. Заменив это `compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')`

на `compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'`

2. Добавив

`configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}`